# Прописать путь Java согласно идентификатору

Tags: java, path

Есть локальний Path: `c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\45\series1\`  , где цифра 45 уникальный идентификатор ,назовем ее id. Как в коде java прописать верно путь, чтобы достучаться к нужной папке series1 .
`c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\{id}\series1\` - пробовал так, но конечно, не срабатывает.
Буду благодарен за ответ!

Comment: `"c:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\" + id + "\series1\"`?

Comment: `String path = Paths.get("c:/Users/User/AppData/Local/Temp", id.toString()).resolve("series1").toString();`
а 45 - это не цифра, это число с двумя цифрами:)

Comment: @tym32167 `"c:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\"` надо две таких `\\` наклонных черты ставить

Comment: @Sergey ну я показал идею, а не готовый код. Но вы правы, надо экранировать спецсимволы.